# Efficiently introduce new level on a factor vector

Tags: r, performance, vector, na, categorical-data

I have a long vector of class factor that contains `NA` values.

```
# simple example
x <- factor(c(NA,'A','B','C',NA), levels=c('A','B','C'))
```

For purposes of modeling, I wish to replace these `NA` values with a new factor level (e.g., 'Unknown') and set this level as the reference level.

Because the replacement level is not an existing level, simple replacement doesn't work:

```
# this won't work, since the replacement value is not an existing level of the factor
x[is.na(x)] <- '?'
x # returns: [1] <NA> A    B    C    <NA> -- the NAs remain
# this doesn't work either:
replace(x, NA,'?')
```

I came up with a couple solutions, but both are kind of ugly and surprisingly slow.

```
f1 <- function(x, uRep='?'){
  # convert to character, replace NAs with Unknown, and convert back to factor
  stopifnot(is.factor(x))
  newLevels <- c(uRep,levels(x))
  x <- as.character(x)
  x[is.na(x)] <- uRep
  factor(x, levels=newLevels)
}

f2 <- function(x, uRep='?'){
  # add new level for Unknown, replace NAs with Unknown, and make Unknown first level
  stopifnot(is.factor(x))
  levels(x) <- c(levels(x),uRep)
  x[is.na(x)] <- uRep
  relevel(x, ref=uRep)
}

f3 <- function(x, uRep='?'){ # thanks to @HongOoi
  y <- addNA(x)
  levels(y)[length(levels(y))]<-uRep
  relevel(y, ref=uRep)
}

#test
f1(x) # works
f2(x) # works
f3(x) # works
```

Solution #2 is editing only the (relatively small) set of levels, plus one arithmetic op to relevel.  I would have expected that to be faster than #1, which is casting to character and back to factor.

However, #2 is twice as slow on a benchmark vector of 10K elements with 10 levels and 10% NA.

```
x <- sample(factor(c(LETTERS[1:10],NA),levels=LETTERS[1:10]),10000,replace=TRUE)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(x),f2(x),f3(x),times=500L) 
# Unit: microseconds
# expr     min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
# f1(x) 271.981 278.1825 322.4701 313.0360  360.7175  609.393   500
# f2(x) 651.728 703.2595 768.6756 747.9480  825.7800 1517.707   500
# f3(x) 808.246 883.2980 966.2374 927.5585 1061.1975 1779.424   500
```

Solution #3, my wrapper for the built-in `addNA` (mentioned in answer below) was slower than either. `addNA` does some extra checks for `NA` values and sets the new level as the last one (requiring me to relevel) and named NA (which then requires renaming by index before releveling, since NA is hard to access -- `relevel(addNA(x), ref=NA_character_))` doesn't work).

Is there a more efficient way to write this, or am I just hosed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fct_explicit_na` followed by `fct_relevel` from the `forcats` package if you want a pre-fab solution. It's slower than your `f1` function, but it still runs in a fraction of a second on a vector of length 100,000:

```
library(forcats)

x <- factor(c(NA,'A','B','C',NA), levels=c('A','B','C'))
```

> ```
> [1] <NA> A    B    C    <NA>
> Levels: A B C
> ```

```
x = fct_relevel(fct_explicit_na(x, "Unknown"), "Unknown")
```

> ```
> [1] Unknown A       B       C       Unknown
> Levels: Unknown A B C
> ```

Timings on a vector of length 100,000:

```
x <- sample(factor(c(LETTERS[1:10],NA), levels=LETTERS[1:10]), 1e5, replace=TRUE)

microbenchmark(forcats = fct_relevel(fct_explicit_na(x, "Unknown"), "Unknown"),
               f1 = f1(x), 
               unit="ms", times=100L)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
>  forcats 7.624158 10.634761 15.303339 12.162105 15.513846 250.0516   100   b
>       f1 3.568801  4.226087  8.085532  5.321338  5.995522 235.2449   100   a
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin function `addNA` for this.

From ?factor:

```
addNA(x, ifany = FALSE)
addNA modifies a factor by turning NA into an extra level (so that NA values are counted in tables, for instance).
```

Comment: Simply doing `addNA` does not set the NA level as the reference level, nor does it replace with the desired level name.  This does not work: `relevel(addNA(x), ref=NA_character_)`